# Segmentation Fault on fprintf iofputs.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gdb

I have the following code:

```
    FILE* fp;
    if(value.empty())
      return ID;
    fp=fopen((tmpDir+"/"+filename).c_str(),"a");
    string sID="";
    if(ID>-1){
      sID=to_string(ID)+"\t";
    }
    string row=sID+drawingID+"\t"+data+"\n";
    fprintf(fp,"%s",row.c_str());
    fclose(fp);
```

Under GDB, the code fails with the following errors:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    __GI__IO_fputs (str=0x4a864 "1000001\t0\t70\t1\n", fp=0x0) at iofputs.c:38
    38  iofputs.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: `fp=fopen((tmpDir+"/"+filename).c_str(),"a");` this isn't C.

Comment: You cant do `tmpDir+"/"+filename` its not c++

Comment: Your code fails to check if `fp` is `NULL` after the call to `fopen`. `fopen` returns `NULL` if the file could not be opened.

Comment: `value.empty()`? `string`? Are you sure the language you are using is called C?

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash, and locate where in ***your*** code it happens. Then check the values of all involved variables to see their values and make sure they are fine. A big hint comes from the output you show us, where it says `fp=0x0`. That means the file is a null pointer.

Comment: @FilipKočica: `c_str()`. It _is_ c++. It's just wrongly tagged and the file extension is misleading too.

Comment: I mean that c isnt c++. @Jean-FrançoisFabre Are you sure he want to write it in C++? maybe he dont and just found this on internet.

Comment: this is a mix between C functions and C++. most people think that C++ & C are the same language...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre please don't edit tags before hearing from the OP. We have no idea what is their intention.

Comment: I know it is, but if he tagged it with C maybe he wanted this code in C.

Comment: no sweat, rollbacked. the issue has nothing to do with the code being C++ or C anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not check the result of `fopen`.

according to the error message `fp`is 0, meaning `fopen` has failed.

I would guess, the tmpDir is non-existent or non-accessable, or the file does not exist, yet.

Comment: I'd suggest that there are more fundamental things wrong with this, such as attempting to concatenate strings using the "+" operator.  While what you say is true, it's not why things are breaking.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer concatenating the strings with `+` is OK if `tmpDir` and `filename` are of type `std::string`. And the usage of `c_str()` suggests that the code is actually C++.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was relying on the "C" tag in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, GDB revealed that the filename parameter was incorrect, which meant that the FILE pointer was 0. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, the filename parameter was correct, but it's a new file. Could that be what caused the FILE pointer to be null? This code works on another machine, but I'm trying to run it on a Raspberry Pi which is failing in this instance.

Comment: To automatically create the file use `fopen(...,"a+")` instead of `fopen(...,"a")`

Comment: Found it! The tmpDir directory was created with 0777 permissions, but for some reason it now has 0755. Thanks for the help.